# Maven : Determine parent POM

Tags: svn, maven-2

I have a whole bunch of mavenised projects, and I want to check that each project has the correct version of a parent pom.

One way could be to checkout each project in turn, and then have a script that reads the parent section.

Or is these some way of determining this from looking at the repository?

Has anyone else had to do something similar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to hack it:

Lots of perl (ab)use to call svn list, grep for my poms, svn export, then XML::XPath.

Ugly ;-)

([Fisheye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) or [VoilaSVN](http://www.voilasvn.com/) might have helped a bit, but I don't think so)

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but, since you asked for something similar, I've already used the [**Versions Maven Plugin**](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) and its [`versions:update-parent`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) (check the [Updating the Parent version](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-parent.html) example) to align parent versions. Maybe it could be useful in your case too.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. This may be useful to ease the pain of ensuring all the projects get updated once they have been audited.